# Generic function accepting object and validators for this object's fields

Tags: validation, typescript

I recently started TS.
I was looking for feedback on my below function (for example maybe it can be written in shorter way). Let's assume we still use the `reduce` function.

The function description:

> Write a function which takes object, and another object which contains
> validators for each of the fields of the main object. Then the
> function should apply the validators and return result, which is also
> an object containing either error messages or not for relevant fields.

Function:

```
type ResultType<T> = { [k in keyof T]: string | null };
function validate<T extends {}>(
  target: T,
  validators: { [k in keyof T]: (value: T[k]) => string | null }
): ResultType<T> {
  return Object.keys(target).reduce((accum, current) => {
    accum[current as keyof ResultType<T>] = validators[
      current as keyof typeof validators
    ](target[current as keyof T]);
    return accum;
  }, {} as ResultType<T>);
}

console.log(
  validate(
    { name: "John", age: 6 },
    {
      name: (p) => (!p ? "String should not be empty" : null),
      age: (p) => (p < 10 ? "Small age" : null),
    }
  )
);
```

Output:

```
{
  "name": null,
  "age": "Small age"
}
```

Comment: You really need that `reduce()`? I think a much better implementation would be to use `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`. Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg)

Answer (score 2):

This looks good to me!  You *could* create another type for the Validators, as you have for the ResultType, ie.

```
type ResultType<T> = { [k in keyof T]: string | null };
type Validators<T> = { [k in keyof T]: (value: T[k]) => string | null }

function validate<T extends Record<string, unknown>> (
  target: T,
  validators: Validators<T>
): ResultType<T> {
```

And add a line space before the function... but it is clear and concise to my eye.